# How can I separate wordpress in backend & frontend with docker container?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I've created two containers for this using the following commands:

```
docker run --detach --name=test-mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" mysql
```

and, with the command `docker inspect test-mysql` I can see the containers IP address `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.20",`

After that, I'm trying to connect it with mysql but I get this error:

```
can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.20' (60)
```

but if I do: "docker exec -it test-mysql bash" I can connect it.

If I want to connect a front end for a wordpress to this mysql container, how should I do it?

I tried with `docker run --detach --name test-wordpress --link test-mysql:mysql wordpress` but is not working and I have nothing in localhost:80
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must expose the ports using -p on docker run command. You can map ports from your container to be accessed from your host:

```
docker run --detach -p 3306:3306 --name=test-mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" mysql
```

The same for wordpress using `-p 80:80`

Comment: Hi, i been trying  "-p 6603:3306", because my 3306 is used, but i have the same error :S "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2' (60)"

Comment: working in a linux instance. The problem can be caused for Mac OX